# Jquery height overlapping my bottom menu

Tags: jquery, css

I am having an issue with my script that makes my last Javascript panel textarea "overlap" my bottom menu bar. I am calculating the height of each panel by how many panels there are and using that as a height after i remove the height of other elements on the page.

I have tried changing both jquery and css to fix this, but something is still causing the overlap.

You might have to look close, but you should be able to see the panel overlaps.

Here is a jsfiddle to help:

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zacharyzac/8ktxeu84/

Comment: I highly suggest looking into redeveloping your layout using Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This is a learning project for me and i am just interested in using jquery in different forms for most of my issues, i will look into flex though, its been on my to do list for a while

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it.
I just changed this is CSS :

```
#container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;                 // Added
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
textarea {
    resize: none;
    background-color: #F3F5F6;
    height:32%;                 // Added
}
```

And changed this in JS:

```
$("#outputContainer, #slider").innerHeight(heightMod);
$("#inputContainer").innerHeight($("#container").height());
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/skavdLkg/)

Now, when width overflows and the horizontal scrollbar appears, it still overlaps.

---

**EDIT**

I fixed the vertical resizing by adding this:

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
  console.log("resizing");

  var newHeight = $(window).height()-( $("#subTitleBar").height()+$("#titleBar").height()+$("#bottomBar").height() );
  $("#container, #inputContainer, #outputContainer").css("height",newHeight);
  $("textarea").css("height","32%");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, in theory this works but upon testing, this does not truly change the height dynamically. if i shrink down my page and refresh this should recalculate the hieght, but if i get too small it still has overlap. do you know why this is?

Comment: I fixed the vertical resize. ;) And lol! It also fixed the horizontal scrollbar overlaping!

Comment: Despite this being a good fox for a resize, it does not fix the issue i am asking about. i would like to get these textarea s with no overlap at all

Comment: Well... You now know what you have to work on! Can't tell life's boring ! ;)